# IMAP protocol commadsand info

Tags: python-3.x, imap, gmail-imap

Where else can i find IMAP protocol commands and information, http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc3501 has been down about for days.I'm trying to work with python's Imapclient.

Comment: Just Google for rfc 3501, it will be mirrored in many places

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.txt and countless other locations.

You'll also have to deal with extension RFCs. Most notably, gmail implements 6851, 6154, 5161 and [their own](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions).